# How to save the picture clicked by the camera in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing a Contacts application. To add the contact image, I have given a dialog box which shows the following 2 options->

1: Take a new image

2: Choose an image from the memory

When I use the 1st option, the picture clicked by the camera is not getting saved. I am getting this in the logcat. What can I do to save the picture clicked by the camera?

```
    ` E/ImageLoader: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{417788c 11498:com.example.contactslist/u0a273} (pid=11498, uid=10273) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{417788c 11498:com.example.contactslist/u0a273} (pid=11498, uid=10273) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6106)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2616)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1844)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1457)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1310)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1030)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromContent(BaseImageDownloader.java:225)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:92)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

    2020-05-25 21:15:51.603 11498-11648/com.example.contactslist E/ImageLoader: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [null]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [null]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For accessing camera you need permission for the camera starting from lollipop OS.

To access the camera first add this line in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    ...
```

Follow this link for complete code:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskManifest